# Intel compiler failing to compile variadic lambda capture with multiple arguments

Tags: c++, lambda, icc

Here is a the minimal example I was able to come up with:

```
#include <utility>
template<class CB, class... ARGS>
void call_lam(CB&& cb, ARGS&&... args) {
     auto lam = [&args...](auto&& callee) { 
                callee(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
     };
     lam(cb);
}

void exec(unsigned, int);

void foo() {
  unsigned x = 25;
  int y = 0;
  call_lam(exec, x, y);
}
```

Above example compiles with both CLang and gcc, but failes with icc 17.0 (as https://godbolt.org/g/tzMY6K shows). The error is as following:

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/move.h(89): error: static assertion failed
>   with "template argument substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type"
>
> static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template
>   argument"
>
> ^ detected during:
>
> instantiation of "_Tp
>   &&std::forward<_Tp>(std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type &&) [with
>   _Tp=unsigned int &]" at line 5 of ""
>
> instantiation of function "lambda [](auto &&)->auto [with =void (&)(unsigned int, int)]"
>   at line 7 of ""
>
> instantiation of "void call_lam(CB &&, ARGS
>   &&...) [with CB=void (&)(unsigned int, int), ARGS=]" at line 15 of "" compilation aborted for  (code 2)
>
> Compiler exited with result code 2

Playing with this example, I have found out that:

- It has to be to distinct types as arguments to `exec`. When using two ints or a single argument, the error goes away
- by replacing the types with something else (for example, `std::string`) and changing manner of passing arguments to `exec` (`const&`) the error can be reported as something else, saying that "overload for `std::move` can not be matched". At this point, it would also fail on icc16. This is slightly modified code: https://godbolt.org/g/qHrU6P

Provided the code is well-formed (as I believe it is), other than replacing lambda with a custom functor (which I do not want to do, as I do not want to capture variable number of arguments with proper references manually through tuples) does anybody see any workarounds here?

Comment: Works for me on ICC 16 on Godbolt, but it does fail with ICC 17. (Your question says something different.)

Comment: @CodyGray, it would fail if you replace the types, for example: https://godbolt.org/g/qHrU6P While looking to simplify the issue, I didn't check the latest version with icc16. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: I think changing `std::forward<ARGS>(args)...` to `std::forward<std::decay_t<decltype(args)>>(args)...` does the workaround

Comment: @W.F. I doubt it would do the right thing, though.

Comment: @SergeyA yup you're right... :/

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will meet your workaround requirements:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<class CB, class... ARGS>
void call_lam(CB&& cb, ARGS&&... args) {
     auto lam = [](auto&&... args2){
         return [&args2...](auto&& callee) { 
                callee(std::forward<std::tuple_element_t<0, std::decay_t<decltype(args2)>>>(std::get<0>(args2))...);
         };}(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<ARGS>(args))...);
     lam(cb);
}

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A&) {
        std::cout << "A(const A&)" << std::endl;
    }
    A(A&&) {
        std::cout << "A(A&&)" << std::endl;
    }
};

void exec(A &, A) {
}

int main() {
  A a;
  call_lam(exec, a, A());
}
```